# Searching/filtering on QuickDialog controller

Tags: ios, uitableview, quickdialog

It'd be nice to be able to enable a UISearchBar to filter long lists for QRadio elements. It's possible that I could do this already with a custom subclass of QuickDialogController, but I had a go and it seems like I'd have to alter a lot of the library code. Anybody implemented this or have any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was less hassle than I thought. I added a block-based way of responsing to UISearchBar events, and sent [a pull request](https://github.com/escoz/QuickDialog/pull/275) to the original creator.